# No Resolution selection option in Twist project using Sahi

Tags: java, firefox, automated-tests, sahi, twist

I am using Twist for Test Automation. I have created a Twist project by following combination:

- Driver: Sahi (for web apps)
- Language: Java
- Browser: Firefox

I have created Scenario. During recording Firefox is opened. In Firefox "Enter start URL text field" is present only. But when I used Sahi Pro 5, there was also "Use with Resolution check box and text field" in browser during recording in which one could enter browser resolution.

Is there any way to use "Use with Resolution check box and text field" option in Sahi with Twist during recording the tests?

Comment: It is Twist 13.1 developed by ThoughtWorks. I have downloaded it from  http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/register?destination=node/226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Use with Resolution check box and text field" is recently added in Sahi_pro and this functionality is not added to Sahi OS. You can check sahi version in Twist and request to thoughtworks to update Sahi underneath Twist.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. With your answer I have understood that it's ThoughtWorks Twist responsibility to update Sahi Pro in Twist. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

By the help of "ThoughtWorks Support ", the following is the answer:

Twist comes bundled with Sahi open source (Sahi OS) version. This feature is not available in the OS version. You will have to set the resolution manually before executing on the browser.